# Jquery plugin. Combobox. Event onChange

Tags: jquery, plugins, combobox, onchange, listen

I have a problem with this plugin http://jquery.sanchezsalvador.com/jquery/page/jquerycombobox.aspx
On my page there are a few select boxes, which transformed by jquery.combobox. As far as it's transformed, it has different html like this

```
<input class="combobox_hidden" type="hidden" name="prtnr" id="prtnr" value="Value">
```

I read documentation about events in this plugin. I wanna listen to onChange event and do something, but it doesn't work.

```
var allsels;
var sels = $("select");
if (sels.length)allsels = sels.combobox();
........
allsels.combobox.onChange=function(){....};
```

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the last line, try

```
allsels.onChange = function () {...};
```

I find this documentation confusing, personally:

> usage:
>
> var elementJQ = $("#id").combobox();
>   elementJQ.combobox.onChange = function(){};
>
> or 
>   $("#id").combobox().onChange = function(){};

So the return result of $('#id').combobox() is a combobox object... with a combobox attribute?

Comment: Still doesn't work. I tried simple alert(); in this function and it has no effect. Maybe it's connected with two different .js files...

Comment: var allsels;
var sels = $("select");
if (sels.length)allsels = sels.combobox();   --- this 3 lines are in init.js
allsels.combobox.onChange=function(){....};  --- this is inline js-code, but follow after init.js

Answer (score 0):

You can always just attach an onchange handler to the original  element.
see the source of the page (specifically the "animation types" select on line 116) in the live example: [jquery.sanchezsalvador.com/samples/example.htm](http://jquery.sanchezsalvador.com/samples/example.htm)

I designed jquery.combobox so that when used, existing code would not break and your event handlers are respected.

@Anton: this was my first jquery widget. I also don't like what I've done with $(selector).combobox, where it is both a function and a state object.